# Unable to send mails in laravel with SMTP (digital ocean) and am getting notification as mail sent.But receiver is not getting mails

Tags: laravel, smtp, digital-ocean

This function is used to send the emails to the user and in the mail, we are taking the username password of the SMTP through a .env file in larval

```
private function pushEmailNotifications($users,$title,$msg,$type)
    { 
         foreach ($users as $value) {

               $template='emails.admin_email';
               $data = array('title' => $title,'type' => $type,'msg' => $msg);
                  try {   
                          Mail::queue($template, $data, function ($message) use ($value,$title) {
                              $message->from('mymailid@gmail.com', 'myapp');
                              $message->to($value)->subject($title);
                          });
                     } 
                  catch (Exception $e) {

                            if (count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {
                                $failures[] = $value;
                            }
                      }
        }

      return "success";
    }
```

This is the code in a .env file:

```
 MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
 MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT = 587
 MAIL_USERNAME = mymailid@gmail.com
 MAIL_PASSWORD = 12345
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tsl
```

Comment: How do you get the notification of email sent?

Comment: after mail, am getting as a notification sent

Answer (score 0):

First I can see that your MAIL_ENCRYPTION should be 'tls', it was mispelt, try that first and let's see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for sending the email rest all are fine.

```
Mail::raw($message_body, function ($message) use ($to,$subject){
            $message->to($to);
             $message->subject("$subject");
 });
```